# Lambda function returning a promise from a function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am working on lambda function using node js. I calling a function which return a promise on then  I am calling a promiseAll. My first function gets a row form DB based on ID, if row is not present I want to return  error response and if present it should call promiseAll.

Following is my code:

```js
return getDetailsOfRow(id).then(function() {
    return Promise.all([
        getDetailsOfA(query1), 
        getDetailsOfB(query2), 
        getDetailsOfC(tripLocationsQuery)
    ]).then(function(values) {
        return combineResults();
    })
});

function getDetailsOfRow(trip) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(query, id, (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            if (results.length < 1) {
                createErrorResponse();
            } else {
                //get the set column values to use for other function   
            }
        });
    });
}

function createErrorResponse() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var response = {
            "isBase64Encoded": false,
            "statusCode": 404,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "text/html"
            },
            "body": "Invalid Key"
        };
        resolve(response);
    });
}
```

promise inside createErrorResponse method is not getting called for lambda function. I am not getting any response from a lambda function. I didn't find any solution. Is it  because I will br  returning a promise inside a promise if call createErrorResponse() from  getDetailsOfRow() ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap `createErrorResponse` function in a promise.

Add the  `createErrorResponse()` in resolve or reject and add `catch` block in `getDetailsOfRow` to catch the error.

Try this

```
return getDetailsOfRow(id).then(function() {
  return Promise.all([
    getDetailsOfA(query1),
    getDetailsOfB(query2),
    getDetailsOfC(tripLocationsQuery)
  ]).then(function(values) {
    return combineResults();
  }).catch( error => {
     return error;
  });
});

function getDetailsOfRow(trip) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(query, id, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      if (results.length < 1) {
        reject(createErrorResponse());
      } else {
        //get the set column values to use for other function
      }
    });
  });
}

function createErrorResponse() {
  return {
    isBase64Encoded: false,
    statusCode: 404,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    body: "Invalid Key"
  };
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error but I am not getting any response also

Comment: Sohail 
I can see {
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "[object Object]",
    "stack": [
        "Error: [object Object]",
        "    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:13:12)",
        "    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:30:51)",
        "    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:57:7)",
        "    at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:69:7)",
        "    at /var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
    ]
} error in cloud watch logs

Comment: Console log in the catch block and see what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here

- You are wrapping the code for `createErrorResponse` in promise which is not required.
- You are not resolving in `getDetailsOfRow` method so there is no way to fulfill the promise.

The code should look like this

```
return getDetailsOfRow(id).then(function() {
  return Promise.all([
    getDetailsOfA(query1),
    getDetailsOfB(query2),
    getDetailsOfC(tripLocationsQuery)
  ]).then(function(values) {
    return combineResults();
  }).catch( error => {
     return error;
  });
});

function getDetailsOfRow(trip) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(query, id, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      if (results.length < 1) {
        reject(createErrorResponse());
      } else {
        resolve(results); // it should be resolved.
      }
    });
  });
}

function createErrorResponse() {
  return {
    isBase64Encoded: false,
    statusCode: 404,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    body: "Invalid Key"
  };
}
```

Comment: I am resolving the promise with result I get in getDetailsOfRow

Comment: can see { "errorType": "Error", "errorMessage": "[object Object]", "stack": [ "Error: [object Object]", " at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:13:12)", " at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:30:51)", " at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:57:7)", " at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:69:7)", " at /var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16", " at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)" ] } error in cloud watch logs

Comment: it is hard to undersrtand from this. can you stringify errorMessage?